# Unexpected behaviour of fancyhdr with pagestyle plain and fancy

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, layout

I don't understand why the header in the second page in the following MWE is red:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[asymmetric]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor,fancyhdr,kantlipsum}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\textsf{\textbf{\large\thepage}}}%
  \fancyhead[RE]{\textsf{\textbf{\large\thepage}}}%
}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\textsf{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{\rightmark}~~{\large\thepage}}}}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\textsf{\textbf{\large\thepage~~~\textcolor{red}{\chaptername~\thechapter~~\leftmark}}}}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\newpage % <-- Toggle on or off
\markboth{}{}
\pagestyle{plain}
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
Here is the text for the indtroduction.

\kant[1-5]

\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{First}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I explicitly defined the page style to be `plain` for this part of the document. Looks like the page style used for this page is that of `fancy`. Why?

If I un-comment the `\newpage` command after the TOC, the output seems to better follow the `plain` headers for the `section*` pages, although I am not 100% sure about that. Either way, I don't know how to remove the red `Chapter 0` in the 4th page. Any help about that? I would like the page to be `empty` on this page.

[image]

I can add

```latex
\clearpage
\begingroup
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \cleardoublepage
\endgroup
```

right before the `pagestyle{fancy}` but this seems to be quite cumbersome. Is there any quicker way for that?

Comment: When you issue `\pagestyle{fancy}`, TeX is still typesetting the last page produced by `\kant[1-5]`, therefore this page is in `fancy` page style. If you put `\cleardoublepage` immediately before, then that page will be in `plain` style because of your earlier `\pagestyle{plain}`. For what you want to do: did you realize that `\tableofcontents` and chapter heads are automatically in `plain` style? Maybe this is where you want to put the red stuff?

Comment: @frougon Thanks for your comment. This issue I described is actually explained very fine in section 23 of the fancyhdr manual, "Switching page styles". So if I do `\newpage  \pagestyle{fancy}  \chapter{First}` as in the second attempt, I get the correct page styles. But it seems that only `\cleardoublepage` removes the red "Chapter 0" in the 4th page. What is the difference between the various new page commands?

Comment: I took the first example and put either `\cleardoublepage` or `\newpage` (as you wish) immediately before `\pagestyle{fancy}`. This results in 3 pages and no red color at all. `\cleardoublepage` flushes the float queue (pending `figure`s and `table`s, at least) and makes sure typesetting resumes from an odd-numbered (right) page. This is meant to easily allow starting parts, chapters, etc. on right pages.

Comment: @frougon If I make the `\kant` longer (for example `[1-10]`), so that the new chapter starts on an odd page (page 5 in this example), there is an empty even page (page 4) with red "Chapter 0" in its header when I use `newpage`. But if I use `cleardoublepage` the page style is plain and there is no red color.

Comment: Yes, this is expected: after `\kant[1-10]\newpage`, TeX is at the beginning of page 4, so the `\pagestyle{fancy}.` applies starting from page 4. OTOH, after `\kant[1-10]\cleardoublepage`, TeX is on page 5 (first odd page after page 3), thus the `\pagestyle{fancy}` is in effect starting from page 5 but **is overridden**, because as I said in my first comment, `\chapter` issues `\thispagestyle{plain}` so that the first page of a chapter is by default in the `plain` page style.

Comment: All right, so what is a "better practice"? Should I prefer `cleardoublepage`?

Comment: I'd suggest you very precisely describe *what you want to obtain.* What is easy to do is to have a different appearance for 1) the page containing `\tableofcontents` 2) the first page of a part or chapter. These are by default automatically in `plain` style. The rest (with a few exceptions like title page) uses the current style according to your use of `\pagestyle` or `\thispagestyle` in the document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137842/discussion-between-tush-and-frougon).